# CSS problems...position fixed disappears

Tags: css, css-position

When I make the browser smaller, and scroll horizontally, the left_nav disappears. I tried changing the position. But that didn't work. Any advice?

```
#left_nav {
    position: fixed;
    height: 95%;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #ededed;
    border-right: 1px solid #aaa
}

#container {
    margin-left: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 75%;
    min-width: 1129px;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 1100;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#left_nav {
position: fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
height: 95%;
width: 100px;
background-color: #ededed;
border-right: 1px solid #aaa
}
```

You should specify the left and top for fixed elements as above. This will place the left nav 0px from the top and left of the *browser window*.

Are you trying to specify it relative to the container? If so, you need to give the left_nav a position of **absolute** and the container a position of **relative**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `min-width: 100px;` to your left_nav, and getting rid of `min-width: 1100;` on container...

Notice you are duplicating the `min-width` attribute; this is a no-no:

```
min-width: 1129px; 
overflow: hidden; 
min-width: 1100;
```